# ¿ como podría obtener los datos de las 2 tablas usando sequelize en node.js?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, sequelize

tengo una BD como la de la imágen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quisiera es poder consultar los pagos que tiene un usuario.
quisiera que la consulta me devuelva algo como esto: correo, nombre apellido, monto, estado, createdAt, es decir, basicamente algunos campos de la tabla usuarios y monto. el problema es que están relacionadas a través de la tabla pedidos (Este modelo ya estaba diseñado así, no fui yo el que lo hice)

los modelos están definidos así:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Pagos = sequelize.define('pagos', {
      id_pagos: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      monto:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      flow_token:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      estado:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      borrado:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
    },
      {
        freezeTableName: true
      }
    );
    Pagos.associate = (models) => {
        Pagos.belongsTo(models.pedidos);
    };
    return Pagos;
  }
```

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Pedidos = sequelize.define('pedidos', {
      id_pedidos: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      pdf:{
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      enviado:{
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
      },
  
      pagado:{
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue:false
      },
  
      mail:{
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue:false
      }
    ,
      recibido:{
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
      },
      borrado:{
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
    },
      {
        freezeTableName: true
      }
    );
    Pedidos.associate = (models) => {
        Pedidos.hasOne(models.pagos);
        Pedidos.belongsTo(models.usuarios);
    };
    return Pedidos;
  }
```

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Usuarios = sequelize.define('usuarios', {
    id_usuarios: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    nombre:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    apellido:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    correo:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    clave:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    recupera_contra:{
      type:DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    borrado:{
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
  },
    {
      freezeTableName: true
    }
  );
  Usuarios.associate = (models) => {
    Usuarios.belongsTo(models.tipos_usuarios);
    Usuarios.hasMany(models.pedidos);
  };
  return Usuarios;
}
```

puedo obtener la unión de las tablas usuarios y pedidos con esta función:

```js
  findAll: (table, req, res) => {
    table.findAll({include: 'pedidos' })
      .then((result) => messages.success(result, res))
      .catch((error) => messages.error(error, res))
  },

app.get(`${route}`,(req,res)=>crud.findAll(db.usuarios,req,res)); //aqui llama a la funcion findAll
```

pero lo que necesito es los datos de la tabla usuarios y pagos, como podría hacerlo ?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2):

Tendrías que utilizar el método de nesting de una tabla a otra, ya que las tienes asociadas.
La función para lo que necesitas tendría

```
Pagos. findAll({
  include: {
    model: usuarios
    include: [
      { model: monto },
      { model: estado }
    ]
  }
}).then...
```

Puedes chequear la documentación aquí: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html

Comment: Hola Pablo, gracias por responder. Eso lo estaba intentando pero no me funciona, dice: include.model.getTableName is not a function.

Comment: Entiendo que getTableName es una función que has escrito dentro de un controlador. El error "is not a function" puede referirse a que hay un error en las exportaciones de módulos.
Comprueba que dentro de tu archivo Js de controlador exportes dicha función (module.exports = "getTableName" (o de la función de controlador si has anidado todas en una sola)) y que está importado en tu carpeta de routes (const getTableName = require ('../controllers/nombreDelArchivoControlador')